# Mule: How to send objects generated in a forEach Loop as multiple attachments in SMTP

Tags: foreach, smtp, mule

I want to send the objects created in a forEach as attachments through SMTP. Is there any way to do this in Mule?

Comment: Please add some more detail to your post. An example of your flow with the components you have already built would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by declaring session variable list and I added the objects created in the for each to this list. Finally I added all the contents of this list to the outbound attachments